# Simulation Study for a Nested Random Effect Model

Tags: r, linear-regression, simulation, lme4, random-effects

I am trying to simulate data based on two random effects and no fixed effects.
The simulated data table contains `nP` projects and within each project `nB` Batches exists. Each Batch has `nR` replicates. Thus, we have a balanced design in the end.
The random effect (i.e. standard deviation) over all Batches is `sd_B`. However, this standard deviation also varies over the different projects with `sd_ranP`.
From my understanding, the random effects from Batch and Product are nested and thus should be estimated by a nested linear mixed model.
I tried to model the simulated data by using the `lme4` package in GNU R.
However, I encounter singularity issues and question myself whether I have understood nested random effects correctly or if there is a mistake in my simulation.

What I tried so far is the following:

First, I define the number of Products, Batches and Replicates together with the corresponding standard deviations.

```r
nP <- 25 #choose number of Products
nB <- 25 #choose number of Batches
nR <- 5 #choose number of Replicates

sd_B <- 100 #Standard Deviation for Batch
sd_ranP <- 10 #Random variability of SD Batch across the different Products
sdRes <- 0.2 #Residual Standard Deviation
```

Next, I sample the standard deviation for each batch over all products. Since the standard deviation of the batches change slightly from one product to the next, I consider this by with the nested random term `sd_ranP` (For simplification reason I assumed that the sampled `sdB` is also normally distributed, fully aware that standard deviations cannot be negative so maybe a log normal sampling would be more correct here. However, I have used values for `sd_B` and `sd_ranP` that no negative values for `sdB` occur.)

```r
#sample the standard deviation of the batches by considering a nested random effect over the products
sdB <- rnorm(n = nP, mean = sd_B, sd= sd_ranP)
```

Afterwards, I sample from `sdB`, add some residual variance `sdRes` which has the same standard deviation across all products and batches and finally I create a data frame from this new y response vector.

```r
#sample from sdB
resB <- unlist(map(.x = sdB, ~rnorm(n = nB, mean = 0, sd = .x)))

#create y and add sdRes
y <- unlist(map2(.x = resB, .y = sdRes, ~rnorm(n = nR, mean = .x, sd = sdRes)))

#create a data frame
df <- data.frame(Product = as.factor(rep(1:nP, each = nB*nR)), Batch = as.factor(rep(1:(nB*nP), each = nR)), y = y)
```

By using the following seed `setseed(29072023)` the simulate data visualized in `ggplot2` show a different batch variability across the projects with a very small residual or within batch variability. This exactly what I would expect.
[image: ggplot of the simulated data]

Finally, I tried to fit the following model:
`model <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|Product/Batch), data = df)` expecting estimated random effects for Batch:Product of around 100, Product of around 10 and Residual of around 0.2.

The interesting point is that in cases where I do not use a seed, in some cases I get exactly these values but in around half of the cases I end up with a singularity issue and a random effect for Product very close or equal to 0. My first thought was that the two random effects might be confounded, however in that case I would expect a singularity issue in all cases and not only in around 50% of the time.

To investigate this observation closer, I repeated the sampling process and model fitting 1000 times. Each time I saved the estimated random effect value for the Product in a vector and created a histogram of the results.
I turned out, that in around 58% of the cases the estimated random effect for Product was below 0.1. However, if these values are neglected, the other 42% show exactly the distribution I would expect (the mean of the distribution is approximately at 10).

[image: Histogramm for the random term Product based on 1000 repetitions]

I hope someone can shed a bit light into my observation ;-)

Here the code for 1000 sampling repetitions.

```
#load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

#outputs of for loop
outm <- NULL

nP <- 25 #choose number of Products
nB <- 25 #choose number of Batches
nR <- 5 #choose number of Replicates

sd_B <- 100 #Standard Deviation for Batch
sd_ranP <- 10 #Random variability of SD Batch across the different Products
sdRes <- 0.2 #Residual Standard Deviation

set.seed(29072023)


for(i in 1:1000){

#sample the standard deviation of the batches by considering a nested random effect over the products
sdB <- rnorm(n = nP, mean = sd_B, sd= sd_ranP)

#sample from sdB
resB <- unlist(map(.x = sdB, ~rnorm(n = nB, mean = 0, sd = .x)))

#create y and add sdRes
y <- unlist(map2(.x = resB, .y = sdRes, ~rnorm(n = nR, mean = .x, sd = sdRes)))

#create a data frame
df <- data.frame(Product = as.factor(rep(1:nP, each = nB*nR)), Batch = as.factor(rep(1:(nB*nP), each = nR)), y = y)

model <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|Product/Batch), data = df)
summary(model)
outm <- rbind(outm, as.data.frame(summary(model)[["varcor"]]))

}
outm$sdcor <- as.numeric(outm$sdcor)
test <- outm %>% dplyr::filter(grp == "Product")

hist(test$sdcor)
```

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help fitting statistical models or creating simulations, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.